# Setting web.Navigation.UseShared in WebProvisioned()

Tags: event-receivers, navigation, top-link-bar, site-settings, global-navigation

I'm trying to configure a team site to "Use Links from Parent" in the "Top Link Bar" whenever a site (web) is created, regardless of what the user chooses on the New SharePoint Site page (gonna hide that section). I'm following this example from [chapter 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=crhCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT684&dq=webprovisioned%20useshared&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS7sKHuvbQAhWJ3SYKHZ0cBAUQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=webprovisioned%20useshared&f=false) of *Inside Microsoft SharePoint 2013*, but I can't get it to work for me.

Here's the relevant code if you can't see the chapter (I added the Kilroy grafitti):

```
public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.WebProvisioned(properties);
        SPWeb web = properties.Web;
        // Let sub site navigation inherit from the parent site
        web.Navigation.UseShared = true;
        web.Description = "Kilroy was here!"; // I added this just to make sure it runs
        web.Update();
    }
```

Strangely enough, If I use PowerShell, it works perfectly: it sets the description and also overrides the `UseParentTopNav` switch parameter, setting the `Navigation.UseShared` property to true.

```
New-SPWeb -Template "STS#0" -UseParentTopNav:$false -url http://mysite.test/TS1/ps1
```

However, I can't seem to get the property to stick when creating a site using the web page. I know that the event receiver is executing, because it replaces the description with "Kilroy was here!"  But, the new site doesn't inherit from the parent until I go into the settings page or set `Navigation.UseShared = $true` with PowerShell. What am I missing?

Comment: Here's a link to the sample code for the book, in case you want to see the whole SharePoint feature from chapter 11 in Visual Studio. [link]http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735674479-files/

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hacking and slashing, I finally settled on creating an asynchronous task in my `WebProvisioned()` event receiver that watches for SharePoint changing `Navigation.UseShared` back to false. I'm not real crazy about this solution though.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

properties.Web.Navigation.UseShared = true;

// the .UseShared doesn't stick if site is created through the gui, so we have try to make to stick it via a background task
Guid webId = properties.Web.ID;
Guid siteId = properties.Web.Site.ID;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) // check twice a second for the next 15 seconds, then give it up
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
            {
                if (web.Navigation.UseShared == false)
                {
                    web.Navigation.UseShared = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Task.Delay(500).Wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```